# Android Studio, Rendering problems

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

I've just installed Android Studio but when i started it tells me:

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE      
Exception Details    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1080029 
at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2235)  
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)   
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)   
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)   
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)   
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)      
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)   
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:70)   
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:39)   
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:65)   
at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:37)  
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:109)   
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:105)   
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)    
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy stack to clipboard
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try to clean and Rebuild the solution, and you have to full access of internet, Android studio is download the content while render first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating SDK only would solve the problem. You can update SDK through Android studio->Help->Check for Update-> and click Update now or open SDK folder and manually run 'SDK Manager.exe' and update all available SDK updates. Sometimes Android studio gets updated but SDK doesn't. Manually update SDK. (Keeping a shortcut of 'SDK Manager.exe' on desktop would be a useful reminder).